Animation featuring a boy, a warrior and animal-tickling villain
I cannot remember the name of this cartoon for my life, but I do remember some key details:

It was American. 
I thought it was Nickelodeon, but I might be wrong.
A flat animation style, but not anime.
The main character was a boy that went looking for this tall, buff warrior.
The boy thought himself such a great fighter but it always got him in trouble.
The villain who the boy was after lived in a pyramid. 
The villain never really hurt anyone. When he would "torture" animals he was actually tickling them with feathers.
The villain would also send these flying monsters after the boy that weren't very smart.
Either the boy or the warrior had a special sword that the villain wanted.
In one episode the main characters were looking for a map and they had to go to two places where flowers grew. At the first place all the flowers, when asked a question, only told the truth. At the second place all the flowers lied.

I bet not all of this is exact to the plot but I hope it's enough information for someone to identify it.

Please see Identify-This-X Questions guide on how to write good identify this movie question. For example add better descriptive title, origin-country, colour, decade, language, plot details, actors etc. of the movie. I highly recommend doing that - otherwise it will be closed in day or two.

That bit about the flowers sounds vaguely familiar. Can you guess as to when the show aired?


I am not sure but is the show Martin The Warrior?
I found this scene and I think it matches your description fairly well.

Sadly no. The main characters were human. Thanks so much for helping!
